# Conceptually, how should this be structured in OOP?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, object

So I have an UIImageView which can be rotated about its center with touchesMoved.

Currently all the code is inside my ViewController, detecting the touch, calculating and tracking current rotation, the image itself and the actual rotation of the image.

But now I want to tidy this up and do it properly. This 'spinner' I have created should be a distinct object which can be instantiated multiple times and dropped in wherever I need it.

So I create my new Spinner class and it keeps track of its own image and angle properties...

But should this be an NSObject with an UIImageView property, or is it an actual UIImageView itself?
And how should the touches be handled, does the ViewController need to play a part or can the object somehow track its own touches?

-

Edited: Still hoping for a clear answer to this old question of mine.

UIControl subclass I suppose kind of makes sense when my spinner is little more than an abstract image which spins and respond to touches.

But when it is more complex with position, velocity, needs to interact with other objects, persist across multiple launches (NSManagedObject subclass?) etc. Touch and image become only a small part of the whole. This is why I was thinking the UIImage would just be another property of the object.

As a simple example think of a bunch of balls bouncing around in a box. They need to bounce off the sides, bounce off each other, spin around, respond to gravity, respond when touched - and persist between launches.

So conceptually, how should this be structured in OOP?

Comment: It sounds like UIControl would be the most appropriate parent class, but you need to explain more about how you want it to be used (by the programmer and by the end user) and where the image comes from if you want sound advice.

Comment: Spinner is a part of my 'model' though isn't it? Doesn't MVC mean my model shouldn't be a UIView subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the 'proper way', as if in OOP there is a single correct answer.

In reality there not one correct design. It is all relative to how you expect the code to be extended and repurposed in the future.

If you really want to prepare yourself for every imaginable extension, then you'll end up with a ridiculously complicated design, and still not cover it all.

In your example: Going from a touch-controlled spinner to something that's part of a 2D physics simulation... that's quite a long jump. Why would I even want to implement that with a common base class?

- If you just want a baseclass for 'something on the screen that can spin'... I'd say that's too generic. There isn't enough added value to justify a new class for that: UIView can already do that.
- If your original object was intended to get user input, then stick to the design pattern of the iOS and subclass UIControl.
- If you envision a physics simulation. Then you probably have a whole class structure that is independent of how it is shown on screen:

A Rigid class to describe mechanical properties (shape, weight, ...) of each object (possibly a class tree. You can use a separate delegates for collision detection. )
A RigidState, describing position and velocity for a Rigid. 
A RigidSimulator, owning a set of Rigids and a RigidState for each rigid. 
A RigidViewController that can creates a UIView (probably an UIImageView) for a given Rigid and can adjust its size and position (given a RigidState). 
...
Something along those lines.

Comment: Don't worry to much about my first example as that was before I began to think it through in more detail. The physics simulation type scenario sounds more like where I'm currently at.

Comment: Okay, in that case not a well formulated question :-/. Anyway, I edited my answer somewhat.

Comment: I sill don't entirely get it lol - but your answer was the best I think

Comment: Happy to elaborate, on what part?

Answer (score 3):

You should use UIControl as the parent class, with a UIImageView property added as a subview.
UIControl has methods you can override for tracking touches.

Comment: I'd go with this way too. You set up easily used events and configurations through your one class.

Answer (score 0):

I have an object that is very similar to this. I call it an MBlob, for MediaBlob. It knows how to do all sorts of things such as how to split itself it 2, combine with another MBlob (resizing appropriately based on the shape), etc. It also knows how to spawn itself into a WebView (loading a URL), get resized (e.g. rotation, gestures), etc. Very handy class for making little apps and I assume many developers have something similar. A similar class is used in my app store apps, QCount (free) and QPlus.

One way to structure such as object is as a child of NSObject, then hook on some protocols for built in items you want to use. For example, my interface looks like this:

```
@interface MBlob : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    id _delegate;
}
```

All properties are implemented as @synthesize varName = _varName in the .m file.

Then you can hook up all kinds of views from this item. This may be overkill, but my MBlob even knows how to launch a preferences editor to edit it's own preferences without troubling the owning VC. Here is some food for thought:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* preview;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* displayView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView* webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIToolbar* toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* mediaType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* mediaValue;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat   aspectRatio; // width:height
@property (nonatomic) BOOL      aspectRatioLocked; 
@property (nonatomic) CGSize    nativeSize;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint   nativeLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField* titleTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIFont* font;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL fullScreen;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WebviewButtonPreferences* webviewButtonPreferences;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PreferencesEditorViewController* preferencesEditorVC;
```

My one caution is that Apple has made a lot of things easy via the built in classes, so don't overdo it. For example in my code above, do I really need a font? I don't know, this isn't active code for my anymore, but it is an example of the kind of object you are describing. If you'll be adding more functionality, go with an umbrella subclass of NSObject and make any other class you want to use a property.

Good luck,

Damien